# NodeJs: how to keep Node server-> Java client connection open

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

```
server.js 
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(4567, 'localhost', function() {
client.write("hello");

client.on('error', function(ex) {
  console.log(ex); });

client.end();
});

client.java
server = new ServerSocket(4567);
client = server.accept();
InputStream input = client.getInputStream();
String inputString = MyClass.inputStreamAsString(input);
system.out.println(inputString);    //inputString gives me "hello"
```

client.java is a time scheduler that runs every 5 seconds, it tries to get the text from Node and prints it. I do not want to close the socket from Node so I can send client.java another message when it is already running. I have 2 issues

1. removing client.end() is not sending the scheduler any message
2. having client.end() is working in first cycle(5 seconds) but when it runs the second cycle(6th second) I have errer Java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed.

how can I not end my socket in Node and be able to send messages to the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [allowHalfOpen](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end) option for the net module?

```
var client = net.connect({port: 4567, allowHalfOpen: true},function() {
    //etc
};
```

Comment: I did, but I'm not sending all messages at once and close the connection. My front end is connected to node to send a message(command like "start/stop" at a user's click. So upon a click it should send the always running scheduler a command(start/stop). for which I want the socket not end at all. is it possible? for now the message is sent once and the socket is closed on the second cycle for the scheduler since I did client.end